# How to handle DST display confusion with fullcalendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, fullcalendar, dst

Okay so I have a repeating event right on the DST boundary. In UTC these are the same times (2018-10-31T21:00:00Z and 2018-11-07T21:00:00Z). I'm using full calendar's local timezone calculation mode.

This is *technically* correct. According to my browsers current time zone, that event across the dst boundary is 1pm.

But as a person who uses a calendar, this is confusing. That event repeats every wednesday at 2pm - why has it all of a sudden changed to 1pm? And worse yet, once I'm across the boundary, it will show as 2pm again!

[image: FullCalendar display]

What are the best ways to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, this is my mistake and nothing to do with fullcalendar.

My recurring event creation logic was forcibly applying a zone offset (and the wrong one) to events across the boundary. I've fixed that up so those recurring events have the correct zone, and fullcalendar is now displaying it correctly.